# Send text message to webmail?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there an email provider that supports sending text messages to a phone # and will send you an email from it?

Does it also support (image) attachments (say I see a funny ad on the subway, can I take a picture send send it)?

Comment: Do you want to send an SMS that triggers an email to be sent to yourself?

Comment: @Barry: I want a friend to send text/images to me from a cell phone. Typically people use their cell number@provider.com but my mobile phone provider doesnt offer this service.

Answer (score 2):

**[Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/)** supports this.  You can have Voice forward text messages in Gmail or to another email address.  `Go to Settings` -> `Voice Settings` -> `Voicemail and Text` tab, and you should see something like this:

[image]

and there is a box after that to input any email address you want.  I believe you can even reply to the SMS messages via email.

However, Google Voice *does not* support multimedia/image messaging, at least yet.

Answer (score -1):

This might be not you are asking about, but it might solve your problem: use some e-mail to sms getaway service. There are many of them and they are very easy to find.

Personally, I'm using smsmail.ru, as it is in Russia, where I am too.